# How does positional emphasis work in Esperanto?

Tags: word-order

The word order in Esperanto sentences is very free. Many learning materials point out that deviating from the "standard" subject-verb-object (SVO) order can be used in Esperanto to put emphasis on a specific part of the sentence.

What emphasis is implied by a non-SVO word order? Is the focus on the parts of the sentence that have been moved to the beginning? Or rather on the ones that have been moved to the end?

Answer (score 2):

As Eduardo says the normal, neutral word order is SVO, and thus if you begin with something else than the subject, that gets emphasized.

Let's take an example sentence:

> *La granda hundo kaj la malgranda kato manĝas bongustan viandon*

What orders are possible and what they emphasize?

- *La granda hundo kaj la malgranda kato manĝas bongustan viandon* (SVO, neutral style)
- *La granda hundo kaj la malgranda kato bongustan viandon manĝas* (SOV, poetic style, somewhat Yoda-like)
- *Manĝas la granda hundo kaj la malgranda kato bongustan viandon* (VSO, emphasis on eating)
- *Manĝas bongustan viandon la granda hundo kaj la malgranda kato* (VOS, main emphasis on eating, secondary emphasis on delicious meat)
- *Bongustan viandon la granda hundo kaj la malgranda kato manĝas* (OSV, emphasis on delicious meat)
- *Bongustan viandon manĝas la granda hundo kaj la malgranda kato* (OVS, main emphasis on delicious meat, secondary emphasis on eating)

If you use the Spanish/French style of putting the adjective attribute after the main word ("hundo granda"), you can in theory double the words. However in many cases the sentences will sound strange.

While the word order is more free in Esperanto than for instance in English (which has a very strict word order), there are some elements, that must be in a certain position as Eduardo says in the end of his answer.

Because Esperanto is largely based on Indoeuropean languages, one usually avoids word orders, where the predicate would be the last element. This is because the predicate is the most important element in those languages.

Final remark, without a separate accusative marker (a grammatical case in this case) you couldn't change the order so freely.

(This is an English adaptation of my text on [Lernu](https://lernu.net/eo/forumo/temo/24954).)

Comment: I don't fully agree with the existence of an overall "neutral" word order in Esperanto. SVO is also the prevalent word order alright, and most second language speakers come from languages that use SVO. But in normal oral everyday use (say renkontiĝoj, familia uzo), everybody moves element around for convenience, rythm, and yes, also emphasis. That's what I tried to convey. I guess my point is: just use the language and stick to THE RULE about word order (according to PMEG)  "En Esperanto la ĉefa regulo de vortordo estas komprenebleco. Oni metu la vortojn en tia ordo, ke la senco estas klara."

Comment: I agree, that _komprenebleco_ should be in the focus (something many writers to a known Esperanto monthly magazine seem to forget). What I tried to convey, is that since SVO is so common, prevalent, order, most people consider it neutral, emphasizing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

## Mallonga respondo:

kion vi mencias unue (komence) kaj ne sekvas SVO, tio estas emfazita. Ni diru ke la surprizo trovi tiun elementon en neatendita loko, tio emfazas ĝin, altiras la atenton al ĝi.

## Iom pli longa respondo:

Imagu paro kiu diskutas, ĉar tria persono havas suspektinde intima rilato kun unu el ili.

> – Vi du babilas multege kaj ofte   laboras ĝis malfrue solaj, kion mi pensu?
>
> – Vin mi amas, ne zorgu kara.

Tie *vin* ne aperas en la kutima loko, do oni iel emfazas ke la amata persono estas tiu kaj ne la alia.

> Mi amas vin, ne zorgu kara.

En tiu kunteksto, tiu frazo tute ne efikus same.

Tamen tiu *surprizo lingva* funkcias nur ĉe tiuj, kiuj ĉefe, kutime, parolas SVO-e.

Mi klarigas unue, Esperanton mi uzas hejme kaj tio evidente influas mian lingvan senton. Ĉe ni, alia ordo povas esti emfaza; la frazo *vin mi amas* ja emfazas *vin*, sed ofte ni ŝanĝas la ordon nur pro tio ke la rezulto estas pli ... konvena pro la fluo de la frazo:

> La ekzameno tiel malfacilis! Ĝin finis nur Andrea.

Oni povus diri, ankaŭ gramatike bone:

> La ekzameno tiel malfacilis! Nur Andrea finis ĝin.

Sed la unua frazo *fluas* pli nature (por ni) ĉar oni havas kiel elementojn: *ekzameno-Andrea* kaj ne *ekzameno-Andrea-ekzameno*.

Do, resume, kelkaj elementoj, en kelkaj kuntekstoj, aspektas emfazite kiam ili ne aperas en la atendita loko. Sed tiu atendita loko povas dependi de la parolantoj.

La lingvo nur postulas ordon/lokon por kelkaj elementoj: [rolvortetoj/prepozicioj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/index.html), elementoj en kunmetaĵoj (ekzemple [precizigaj antaŭelementoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/vortfarado/principoj/antauelementoj.html)), ... Sed ne por subjekto, verbo, objekto. Emfazo per ŝanĝo de tiu ordo ne estas garantiita.

Comment: Kion signifas "la lingvon mi uzas familie"? La maniero, kiel vi uzas Esperanton familie? Aŭ alia lingvo (ekz., iu nacia lingvo), kiun vi uzas familie?

Comment: @das-g dankon. Mi korektis la frazon kaj klarigis ke temas pri hejma uzado de la lingvo, kun denaskuloj.

Comment: @das-g jes, tajperaro. Korektita.